# Dell xps laptop ~ power switch ribbon cable broke

Tags: dell-xps

Is there a way to fix a broken ribbon cable? This happened yesterday and my friend told me I have to change the entire palmrest for it. What are my options in here?[image: Preview]

Comment: See the procedure detailed in the article [How to repair broken ribbon cable](http://stcwk.blogspot.fr/2010/03/how-to-repair-broken-ribbon-cable.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are way hard to fix, especially with how tiny many of them are. I recommend using the model number to look up the service manual of your pc. There, you will find a list of parts so you can order a replacement. They are fairly cheap, usually.